# Submit Form With Ajax to MySQL

Tags: mysql, forms, jquery

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

For sometime I've been searching for a tutorial/article that shows me how to set up a form and submit the user input to a mySQL database using AJAX.

Although this doesn't show me how to send the data to the database, [this](http://www.elated.com/articles/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/) article provided me with a good starting pointing and it also gave me the 'look and feel' in respect of online messages which I would like to incorporate into my form.

I've now started to adapt the example script but I'm having difficulty in submitting the data to my database.

In the form I've changed this section:

```
   $.ajax( {
          url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
          type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
          data: contactForm.serialize(),
          success: submitFinished
        } );

  }
```

to

```
 $.ajax( {
      url: contactForm.attr( 'savecontact.php' ) + "?ajax=true",
      type: contactForm.attr( 'post' ),
      data: contactForm.serialize(),
      success: submitFinished
    } );
  }
```

and in the PHP script, I've changed this to now read:

```
<?php

// Read the form values
$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['senderName']);
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['senderEmail']);
$message = isset( $_POST['message']);


if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $message ) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO `contact` (senderName, senderEmail, message) VALUES ('$senderName', '$senderEmail', '$message')";  
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}           
// Return an appropriate response to the browser
if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
  echo $success ? "success" : "error";
} else {
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thanks!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ( $success ) echo "<p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>" ?>
  <?php if ( !$success ) echo "<p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>" ?>
  <p>Click your browser's Back button to return to the page.</p>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

The problem I'm having, is that upon sending the form, the `sending` message appears on screen and continues to be stuck on this message and non of the data is sent to my database and I must admit I'm really not sure why.

I appreciate that because of my lack of experience there may be an easier way to achieve the results I would like and I may be looking at this too simplistically, but I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: There's no such attribute as `savecontact.php` on a form. You should rollback your JavaScript code.

Comment: Hi @Truth, thank you for this. I've made the changes, as highlighted in my post below. Kind regards

Comment: You need to post more of your php - i.e. where do the variables $senderName, $senderEmail and $message get set?

Comment: Hi @bcmcfc, thank you for taking a look at my post. I've added my full PHP script o my original post. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
contactForm.attr( 'savecontact.php' )
```

To:

```
contactForm.attr( 'action' )
```

And

```
type: contactForm.attr( 'post' ),
```

To

```
type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
```

Since `attr` is used to read tag attributes. The `action` attribute of your form tag in this case.

Depending on your form's `method` attribute, you will have to use `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays to get values submitted through AJAX or you may also want to use `$_REQUEST` (not recommended way though)

Comment: Hi @Blaster, thank you for taking the time to help me with this. As I said in my original post, I'm relatively new to this, so my inexperience had clearly led to these initial errors. I have made the changes you suggest, and although the screen is no longer stuck on the `sending` message, I now receive `There was a problem...` message, unfortunately meaning that the data hasn't been transferred to my database, Could you tell me please, have you any ideas where I'm going wrong? Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Blaster's answer, your php code also needs some fixing:

```
$senderName = isset( $_POST['senderName']);
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['senderEmail']);
$message = isset( $_POST['message']);
```

Here you're setting those variables to a boolean value of whether or not the POST variable was set, and not the actual value.

```
$senderName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senderName']);
$senderEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senderEmail']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
```

That should get things working, but is vulnerable to SQL injection. The `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated and it is recommended to learn PDO or MySQLi and prepared statements. Please see [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) in the PHP manual for more information.

Comment: Hi @bcmcfc, thank you very much for your help. The data now saves into my database which is great. However, even though this happening, I momentarily receive the `Sending ` message before receiving the `There has been a problem`. This means the form doesn't disappear from screen. I've done some testing and the problem lies around the lines above that were changed. i.e. As soon as this `$senderName = isset( $_POST['senderName'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderName'] ) : "";` is changed the functionality fails to work correctly.Have you any ideas please? Kind regards